# Implementing generic WS retry call

Tags: java

I want to implement generic retry call mechanism to my WS calls.
The WS calls may vary, so the results have different types.
Let's say there are two types of call:

```
int result = wsPortType.callMethod(arg1, arg2);
MyObject result = anotherWsPortType.callSomeOtherMethod(arg);
```

I could do something like this for all the WS call methods:

```
int result;
try
{
  result = wsPortType.callMethod(arg1, arg2);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  try
  {
    result = wsPortType.callMethod(arg1, arg2);
  }
  catch (Exception ex0)
  {
    // TODO
  } 
}
```

But that I would have to write for every WS call, which I don't want to.

I was thinking about something like this:

```
public class RetryWsCall
{
  public interface RetryCallInterface
  {
    public <T> T RetryCallMethod();
  };

  public <T> T callWs(RetryCallInterface retryCallImplementation, int retryCount) 
  {
    try
    {
      return retryCallImplementation.RetryCallMethod();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      try
      {
        return retryCallImplementation.RetryCallMethod();
      }
      catch (Exception ex0)
      {
        // TODO
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

And then just call something like:

```
RetryWsCall retryWsCall = new RetryWsCall();
retryWsCall.callWs(new RetryWsCall.RetryCallInterface()
{
  @Override
  public <T> T RetryCallMethod()
  {
    return wsPortType.callMethod(arg1, arg2);
  }
}, 2);
```

But I just cannot use it correctly, so that the generic method returns the correct value type.

Comment: It's quite a complex subject, you'll probably need some kind of exponential backoff, the right logs, maybe some "max attempts" too. If you need this for a production app, I'd suggest using an already existing and widely used 3rd party lib. It's still a interesting subject and should be quite educative developing it yourself though :) For ex https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to correctly use the generic method. I realized that I should have made the question simpler and not mentioning the WS calls since it is not the main issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. The issue was that I was unable to correctly use generics.
I'm adding max attemts and intentionally skipping logging in this sample.

The class handling the retries could look like this:

```
public class RetryWsCall
{ 
  public interface RetryCallInterface
  {
    public <T> T RetryCallMethod();
  };

  public <T> T callWs(RetryCallInterface retryCallImplementation, int retryCount) 
  {
    try
    {
      return retryCallImplementation.RetryCallMethod();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      if (retryCount > 0)
      {
        while (retryCount > 0)
        {
          try
          {
            return result = retryCallImplementation.RetryCallMethod();
          }
          catch (Exception ex0)
          {
            retryCount--;
          } 
        }
      }
      throw ex;
    }
  }
}
```

Then I can call:

```
RetryWsCall retryWsCall = new RetryWsCall();
int result = retryWsCall.callWs(
        new RetryWsCall.RetryCallInterface() 
                {
                  @Override
                  public Integer RetryCallMethod()
                  {
                    return wsPortType.callMethod(arg1, arg2);
                  }
                },
        numberOfAttempts
);
```

or

```
RetryWsCall retryWsCall = new RetryWsCall();
MyObject result = retryWsCall.callWs(
        new RetryWsCall.RetryCallInterface() 
                {
                  @Override
                  public Integer RetryCallMethod()
                  {
                    return anotherWsPortType.callSomeOtherMethod(arg);
                  }
                },
        numberOfAttempts
);
```